# Linkedin posts navigates correctly initially but then immediately redirects back to the home page when using the mobile app

Tags: ios, wordpress, linkedin-api

When using the linkedIn Mobile app to view our company's posts, when clicking on it within the mobile app, it navigates correctly but then immediately redirects back to the home page. This behaviour does not happen on the desktop.

Any ideas on how to correct this?

When adding the link, we are simply copying and pasting the url into the "edit post" textbox for creating a new post in linkedIn.
Generally, if not always, we are creating new posts from the desktop.

We need the mobile app version to navigate correctly without the additional redirect.
You are however taken to the linked post correctly when you hit the back button from within the mobile app.